# Getting All Object attribut names reursively

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

is there any way to get all attribute names of an object `Company` recursively:
ExpectedOutput `id, age, address {street, zipCode}, employee {firstName, LastName, profile}, profile {role, experience}.` can we get this output without using `SchemaFactoryWrapper`..

```
class Company{
  String id;
  int age;
  Address address;
  List<Employee>
}
  class Employee{
  String firstName;
  String LastName
  Profile profile;
}
class Address{
  String street;
  String zipCode;
}

class Profile{
  String role;
  int experience
}
```

Comment: Uhm you mean like using Jackson for json serialization? Jackson is included in spring boot for e.g. @RestController classes. Can you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it's absolutely clear !! is tere any way to get the string output!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :

```
private HashSet<String> traverse(Class<?> outputFilter) {
    Field[] objectFields = outputFilter.getDeclaredFields();
    HashSet<String> fieldNames = new HashSet<>();
    for (Field field : objectFields) {
        fieldNames.add(field.getName());
        if(isValidField(field)){
            fieldNames.add("{");
            Class<?>  clazz =  (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            fieldNames.addAll(traverse(clazz));
            fieldNames.add("}");
        }
    }
    return fieldNames;
}



private boolean isValidField(Field field){
    if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(List.class) |
            field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Set.class)){ //TODO Map
        Class<?> clazz = ((Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
        return !clazz.isPrimitive() && !clazz.equals(String.class);
    }
    else if (field.getType().equals(Object.class) && !field.getType().isPrimitive())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).